# how to scroll canvas with paperjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I have not been able to scroll through canvas move whole paper horizontally and 
vertically.

It is possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/PaperJS/paper-full.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/PaperJS/paper-core.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('odbCanvas');
      paper.setup(canvas);
      var path = new paper.Path();
      path.strokeColor = 'white';
      var start = new paper.Point(100, 100);
      path.moveTo(start);

      path.lineTo(start.add(0,40));
      path.lineTo(start.add(40,40));
      path.lineTo(start.add(40,0));
      path.lineTo(start.add(0,0));

      paper.view.draw();

      path.on('mousedrag', function (event) {
          this.position = event.point;
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `paper.view.scrollBy(new Point(x, y))` to scroll the *whole* [View](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/)

Here's some example code:

```js
// Draw a Rectangle for reference
var rect = new Path.Rectangle(new Point(200, 100), new Point(50, 50))
rect.strokeColor = 'black'
rect.strokeWidth = 1

// Create a Tool so we can listen for events
var toolPan = new paper.Tool()
toolPan.activate()

// On drag, scroll the View by the difference between mousedown 
// and mouseup
toolPan.onMouseDrag = function (event) {
  var delta = event.downPoint.subtract(event.point)
  paper.view.scrollBy(delta)
}
```

And here's a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VZFBb4MwDIX/isWlIFUpndRLp17WXadV27Qdxg4hmIJIHZQEUFX1v88J1arlRN6znz+cS0LyhMk2ee/QqyZZJspU4b5awbOVE0h4Q+UlHTVCbSxYrNEiKSxolOGqPOyAcIKD9I34K06jZFry6UOeL2Gd59kS7uKGtU2eZQWFCOG8NR3ujeYRO1iUWqpu8c/7aivfsLcuqCCm21uUHpnvwxgNzsCEoCSBbp1Hiqw4Ink3g3quOrA9s/ayRytCZ8oEN09I5duRQ4MWZ7wSVFYel+CUNVqDbxA+W+4vz/G7auvbNqBEPyHPPZnBYWUmgpggqZqlob/PMfQSJN7vkXnqgXiuIUgjbwaXgoBPoK5Qe8k10REhNm5PuKH0lnHnFtEHMZvb5l8bmVLM1E/nNMawf33kBy55cV3scMn2++f6Cw==) for this (drag your mouse on the canvas)

---

Side note: You don't need to include both paper-core.js and paper-full.js. Use one or the other, depending whether you need PaperScript support as well (paper-full.js includes PS as well).

Comment: `scrollBy()` is deprecated.  The last line should now read `paper.view.translate(delta.multiply(-1))` (the direction sense of `scrollBy()` and `translate()` are reversed).